# Sum of column in where clause in laravel eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have a FamilyMember model and a SubscriptionCharge model, SubscriptionCharge store charges of multiple months of each family member.
I have to select members whos sum of charges greater than a specific amount.

```
$members=FamilyMember::whereHas('subscription_charge', function ($qq) {
   $qq->where(); // how to check sum of column 'amount' in where
})->get();
```

How to check the sum of column 'amount' in a where condition

Comment: Are you using MySQL?

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comment, Updated Answer

```
$memeber = FamilyMember::query()
    ->join(DB::raw('("SELECT subscription_charge.family_member_id, SUM(subscription_charge.amount) as total_charges FROM subscription_charge GROUP BY subscription_charge.family_member_id HAVING SUM(subscription_charge.amount) > 
AMOUNT_YOU_WANT") as sub_table'), function($join) {
         $join->on('sub_table.family_member_id', '=', 'family_member.id');
    })->get();
```

***Note: Not tested***

Comment: showing sql error SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1111 Invalid use of group function (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `family_members` where exists (select * from `subscription_charges` where `family_members`.`id` = `subscription_charges`.`family_member_id` and sum(amount) > 10))

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be able to do something like this. (I'm at the airport so unable to test it.)

```
$members=FamilyMember->join(DB::raw('(SELECT family_member_id, SUM(amount) AS sum_of_charges 
            FROM subscription_charge
            WHERE family_member_id = x
            GROUP BY family_member_id
//                  (or HAVING family_member_id = x ?)
            ) charges'),
        function($join)
        {
           $join->on('FamilyMember.id', '=', 'charges.family_member_id');
        })
       ->select(                
            'FamilyMember.id',
            'charges.sum_of_charges'
        )
        ->where('sum_of_charges', '>', 'Y')
    })->get();
```